# Sending multipart email from php, only download shows not the actual message

Tags: php, email, multipart

I'm struggling with sending my multipart email with plain text version as well as with HTML. Unfortunately when I receive it in Gmail it shows as downloadable message only as shown below:

[image]

The code is pasted below and although I went over like 100 questions here on SO I'm still stuck.

```
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: donotreply@someaddress.com\r\n";
        $headers .= "Subject: Test mail\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary=" . $boundary . "\r\n";

        $message = "This is a MIME encoded message."; 
        $message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
        $message .= "Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";
        // plain text version
        $message .= $plainTextMessage;

        $message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
        $message .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";
        // html version here
        $message .= $htmlMessage;

        $message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "--";

        return @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Don't built your own mime emails. Use PHPMailer or Swiftmailer. Both make this painless and much easier.